# Jquery Datatable update cell text value and colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a datatable which has ajax sourced data.

I have some function which validates the data in table cell by cell and changes cell color to red if validation failed. also having an column with no data initially and updates its data later. I set `rowId` as `ip_address` to identify that row based on ip.

Now i want to update the empty cell whose ip matches rowid in table.

I tried `$("#devices_table td:nth-child(3)").text('hi');`

which updates all rows for 3rd column, but i want to update only one row matching that `rowId`.

```
    tbl1 = $('#devices_table').dataTable({
    autoWidth: false,
    scrollX: true,
    scrollY: 400,
    paging: false,
    select:{ style: 'multi' },
    info: false, // This will prevent showing message 'Showing 1 of N rows'
    serverSide: true,
    aoColumns: [    { title: "Result", data:'Result', defaultContent: '', name: 'Result'},
                    { title: "IP Address",data: "IP_Address", name:'IP_Address'}, ],
    fnRowCallback: function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
           $('td', nRow).attr('nowrap','nowrap');
            return nRow;
            }, // This is for content wrap in column
    ajax: "/get_device_table", // call for data
    rowId: 'IP_Address',
```

this is my table defination.

`tbl1.fnUpdate('abc' , $('tr#192.168.30.20'), 0 );`
`$("#devices_table").children().children()'192.168.30.20'].children[0].innerHTML = "Hi";`
`$('#devices_table tr:eq('+rowid+') td:eq(0)').text('ChangedText');`

and these are few things which I tried but didnt work for me.

I am new to datatables and jquery, so this code can have stupid mistakes too.. please correct me if any. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do this validation within `fnRowCallback`.  What is the validation checking?

Comment: no.. its background api and processing of data. its not validation of datatable values.

Comment: var parent = $('#devices_table tr#'+ rowId);
parent.find('td:nth-child(3)').text('hi');

Comment: @Shital Replace those two line in function that validates,and check whether it is working or not.

Comment: Thanks @ShekharPankaj.. i tried that too but did not work.

Comment: what was the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Issue was due to setting ip address as `id`

changed `.` in ip to `-` and added `className` to `column` and it worked.

and following code of line,
`aoColumns: [
          { title:"Result", data:'Result', defaultContent:'',className:'result'},
          { title: "IP Address",data: "IP_Address", className:'IP_Address'}, ]`

`$('#192-168-32-24').find('td.result').html('hi')`